# few questions about Unity5 & NGUI on ipad Mini

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ngui, ipad-mini

[image: red lines point to the problem]

When all functions are finished on Unity5 Editor, I build it on iPad mini2. But some issues are followed:

a. The "made with unity" logo and text is always flickering, with constant frequency to show and hide. However, I ever made the logo in the scene, I don't know how to remove it.

b. Thumb of ProgressBar always show the previous positions when I drag it. Which is normal in the Editor.

c. The arial font is so much blur either Chinese nor English. That is same in the Editor.

But a & b are never happened in Unity Editor. Would you help to solve this problems or give me some hints?

Thanks!